# How do I export multiple lists to one csv?

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup

How do I add each iteration of this list to a csv file for an unknown number of columns.

This is because the genre list and not the same length for each film.

If the film only has less than the max then the other columns I would expect to be empty.

I would expect the output to look a little like the following;

```
WebPage,Film,Genre1,Genre2,Genre3, ..... maxnumberofGenres
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6644200/, A Quiet Place, Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi
```

How do I solve the problem?

```
import requests
from googlesearch import search 
import csv
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time


start_time = time.time()

colnames = ['title']
data = pandas.read_csv('D:/Desktop/webScrapeMovieInfo/mediaDataForGenreScrape2.csv', names=colnames, header=None)
my_list = data["title"]
my_list = list(my_list)
my_list = my_list[1:]
length = len(my_list)
for film in my_list:
    query = film + " imdb"
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2):
        print(j)
        page = requests.get(j)
        response = page.status_code
        if response == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
            genreData = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"subtext"})
            filmtitle = soup.find("h1")
            filmtitle = filmtitle.contents[0]
            print(filmtitle)
            links = []
            for h in genreData:
                a = h.find_all('a')
                aLength = len(a) - 1
                a1 = a[0]
                for b in range(0,aLength):
                    print(a[b].string)



np.savetxt("filmWebPages.csv", j, delimiter=",", fmt='%s', header="imdbPageOfFilms")


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: The code you have written is kinda irrelevant to debugging. Store the whole thing as  list of lists. Give us a sample here. I'll let you know how to store that.

Comment: Please provide a sample

Comment: savetxt is designed to save a 2d array of numbers.  Variations are better done with your own line by line text write.

Answer (score 1):

To extract all genres you could use this script - it will save it to the CSV and print to the screen too:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?pf_rd_i=moviemeter&genres=action&explore=title_type,genres'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

rows = []
for h3, genres in zip(soup.select('.lister-item-header'), soup.select('.lister-item-header ~ p .genre')):
    title = h3.select_one('a').text
    url = h3.select_one('a')['href']
    genres = [*map(str.strip, genres.text.split(', '))]
    rows.append([title, url, genres])

#find all the genres we have:
all_genres = sorted(list(set(sum((row[2] for row in rows), []))))

#transform all rows to include True/False if they belong to certain genre
for row in rows:
    row[2] = [g in row[2] for g in all_genres]

#print header
print('{: <40}{: ^20}'.format('Name', 'URL') +  ''.join('{: ^10}'.format(g) for g in all_genres))

#print all rows
for title, url, genres in rows:
    print('{: <40}{: <20}'.format(title, url), end='')
    print(''.join('{: ^10}'.format('X' if g else '-') for g in genres))

#save to csv
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(['Name', 'URL'] + all_genres)
    for title, url, genres in rows:
        csvwriter.writerow([title, url, *['✔' if g else '' for g in genres]])
```

Prints:

```
Name                                            URL           Action  Adventure Animation   Comedy    Crime     Drama    Fantasy   Mystery    Sci-Fi   Thriller 
Spider-Man: Far from Home               /title/tt6320628/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Top Gun: Maverick                       /title/tt1745960/       X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
The King's Man                          /title/tt6856242/       X         X         -         X         -         -         -         -         -         -     
La Casa de Papel                        /title/tt6468322/       X         -         -         -         X         -         -         X         -         -     
Troonide mäng                           /title/tt0944947/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Crawl                                   /title/tt8364368/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Alita: Sõjaingel                        /title/tt0437086/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Tasujad: Lõppmäng                       /title/tt4154796/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Terminaator: Tume Saatus                /title/tt6450804/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
The Witcher                             /title/tt5180504/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Hellboy                                 /title/tt2274648/       X         X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -     
Point Blank                             /title/tt2499472/       X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         X     
Shazam!                                 /title/tt0448115/       X         X         -         X         -         -         -         -         -         -     
Stuber                                  /title/tt7734218/       X         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -         -     
Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw   /title/tt6806448/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         -     
Tippkutt                                /title/tt0092099/       X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
John Wick 3: Parabellum                 /title/tt6146586/       X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -         X     
Ämblikmees: Uus universum               /title/tt4633694/       X         X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -     
S.H.I.E.L.D.i agendid                   /title/tt2364582/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
The Boys                                /title/tt1190634/       X         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -         -     
Designated Survivor                     /title/tt5296406/       X         -         -         -         -         X         -         X         -         -     
Kapten Marvel                           /title/tt4154664/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Viikingid                               /title/tt2306299/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Mulan                                   /title/tt4566758/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Bond 25                                 /title/tt2382320/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         X     
Spider-Man: Homecoming                  /title/tt2250912/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Murder Mystery                          /title/tt1618434/       X         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -         -     
Pandora                                 /title/tt10207090/      X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         X         -     
Shaft                                   /title/tt4463894/       X         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -         -     
Jessica Jones                           /title/tt2357547/       X         -         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -     
Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker        /title/tt2527338/       X         X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -     
Leegion                                 /title/tt5114356/       X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         X         -     
Anna                                    /title/tt7456310/       X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         -         X     
Vibukütt                                /title/tt2193021/       X         X         -         -         X         -         -         -         -         -     
NCIS: Kriminalistid                     /title/tt0364845/       X         -         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -     
Välk                                    /title/tt3107288/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Wonder Woman 1984                       /title/tt7126948/       X         X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -     
Titans                                  /title/tt1043813/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Ghostbusters 2020                       /title/tt4513678/       X         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -         -     
Power Rangers                           /title/tt3717490/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Charlie's Angels                        /title/tt5033998/       X         X         -         X         -         -         -         -         -         -     
Mehed mustas: globaalne oht             /title/tt2283336/       X         X         -         X         -         -         -         -         -         -     
Swamp Thing                             /title/tt8362852/       X         X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -     
Queen of the South                      /title/tt1064899/       X         -         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -     
Tasujad: Igaviku sõda                   /title/tt4154756/       X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         X         -     
Gotham                                  /title/tt3749900/       X         -         -         -         X         X         -         -         -         -     
Godzilla: King of the Monsters          /title/tt3741700/       X         X         -         -         -         -         X         -         -         -     
Shingeki no kyojin                      /title/tt2560140/       X         X         X         -         -         -         -         -         -         -     
Escape Plan: The Extractors             /title/tt6772804/       X         -         -         -         X         -         -         -         -         X     
Thor: Ragnarök                          /title/tt3501632/       X         X         -         X         -         -         -         -         -         -
```

And saves `data.csv`. Here's screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer +. If I want to read about the specific syntax {: <40}{: <20}  can you recommend anything please? It is this particular syntax usin : and < ^ that I am interested in.

Comment: @QHarr I would start at official documentation https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec But this one site is really well done https://pyformat.info/